# When change an object inside a CollectionView multiple objects are affected

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

If I hide an image visibility in CollectionView, multiple image visibility is affecting but image Tapped event fires once.

Simplified CollectionView xaml..

```
<CollectionView x:Name="favCollectionView"
ItemsSource="{Binding FavoriteCollection}"
RemainingItemsThresholdReachedCommand="{Binding GetNextDatas}"
RemainingItemsThreshold="1"
ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
ItemsLayout="VerticalList"
SelectionMode="Single">
   <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
          <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding TargetText}"/>
          <Image Grid.Row="0" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="seeResult.png">
             <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                 <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Tapped_TranslatedResult"/>
             </Image.GestureRecognizers>
          </Image>
        </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Code behind..

```
void Tapped_TranslatedResult(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var img = sender as Image;
    if (img != null)
    {
        img.Opacity = 0;
    }
}
```

For example, If I have 50 rows in CollectionView and tapped once top second image item, next ninth image's visibility is changed too and again next ninth one too, so on..

What could be the problem?

Comment: do not directly modify the UI elements of templated controls.  You should bind `IsVisible` to a model property and modify the model instead

Comment: Hi Jason, your answer is the solution to my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the Image to ImageButton and then added Command parameter. The key was the Jason's comment. Binding the Model property to my ImageButton's IsVisibility property and it worked correctly.